# SQLの結合についての解説が知りたい

Tags: sql

以下の問題は基本情報技術者試験の問題です。SQL文で「結合」という意味がどうもわかりません。書籍の解説を読んだのですが説明が簡素でわかりません。参考サイトを見て大体理解したのですが以下の`知りたい事`が知りたいです。
これはどういった理屈で抽出されているのでしょか？

###### 知りたい事

結合すると表がどのように変化するのか知りたいです。

参考サイト: https://www.fe-siken.com/kakomon/31_haru/q29.html

参考書:
[令和04年 イメージ&クレバー方式でよくわかる 栢木先生の基本情報技術者教室 (Amazon.co.jp)](https://www.amazon.co.jp/gp/product/4297123932/)

##### 問題

以下の学部と学生表に対してSQLを実行した結果として正しいものはどれか？

```
SELECT 氏名 FROM 学生、学部
 WHERE 所属=学部名 AND 学部.住所 = '新宿'
```

###### 学生

| 氏名 | 所属 | 住所 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 応用花子 | 理 | 新宿 |
| 高度次郎 | 人文 | 渋谷 |
| 午前花子 | 経済 | 新宿 |
| 情報太郎 | 工 | 渋谷 |

###### 学部

| 学部名 | 住所 |
| --- | --- |
| 工 | 新宿 |
| 経済 | 渋谷 |
| 人文 | 渋谷 |
| 理 | 新宿 |

###### 回答

| 氏名 |
| --- |
| 応用花子 |
| 情報太郎 |

Comment: 参考: https://www.fe-siken.com/kakomon/31_haru/q29.html

Comment: ちなみに「関係代数」や「集合論」というのは知っていますか？

Comment: 調べています。がこの場合はどうなるのでしょうか？http://www.pursue.ne.jp/jouhousyo/SQLDoc/RDBsousa.html

Comment: 回答に情報太郎とありますが、学生表には存在しません。その例であれば情報花子の間違いかと思われますが、そこは大丈夫ですか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FROM 学生, 学部`により、「学生」テーブルと「学部」テーブルの直積からなる表(クロス結合表)が作られます。

###### 学生×学部

| 学生.氏名 | 学生.所属 | 学生.住所 | 学部.学部名 | 学部.住所 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 応用花子 | 理 | 新宿 | 工 | 新宿 |
| 応用花子 | 理 | 新宿 | 経済 | 渋谷 |
| 応用花子 | 理 | 新宿 | 人文 | 渋谷 |
| 応用花子 | 理 | 新宿 | 理 | 新宿 |
| 高度次郎 | 人文 | 渋谷 | 工 | 新宿 |

(長いので以下省略)

これに対して、`WHERE 所属=学部名`により、`所属=学部名`の行がフィルタされます。結合してもカラム名が重複しないので`所属=学部名`でもいいのですが、省略せずに書くなら`学生.所属=学部.学部名`です。

さらに`学部.住所 = '新宿'`によりフィルタされます。こちらは結合表でカラム名が重複しているので`学部`を明示する必要があります。

最後に`SELECT 氏名`で`氏名`カラムだけが選択されます。

これは原理的な話で、実際のRDBMSでは処理が少なくなるようよしなにやってくれるので全体を結合した表を作ったり順番通りフィルタしたりはしません。

Answer (score 0):

> 結合すると表がどのように変化するのか知りたいです。

参考サイト: https://www.fe-siken.com/kakomon/31_haru/q29.html の解説がわかりやすいと思います。

[image: 解説]

また、結合に関しては https://atmarkit.itmedia.co.jp/ait/articles/1703/01/news186.html にわかりやすい例が記載してあります。他サイトの引用ばかりで申し訳ありませんが参考になれば幸いです。

Comment: 自分の記述の補足として他サイトの記載を引用するのはかまいませんが、単なるコピペはやめましょう。またリンク先が失われる場合もあるので、(コピペではなく自分の言葉で)リンク先を見なくても完結できる要約を記載してください